# How to get the specific <td> while scraping a web page table using a DOM?

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I've a `table`, of whose number of columns can change depending on the configuration of the scrapped page (I have no control of it). I want to get only the information from a specific column, designated by the columns heading.

Sample table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Marks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>70</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My working PHP code to display all columns:

```
foreach($html->find("table#table2 tr td") as $td) {
  $code = $td;
  echo $code;
}
```

Needed code format:

```
foreach($html->find('table#table2 td') as $td) {
  /* Get td1 data */ 
  /* Code1 to store td data 1 */

  /* Get next td data */ 
  /* Code2 to store td data 2 */

  /* Get the next td data */ 
  /* Code3 to store td data 3 */
}
```

I want to extract the output and store it to a DB table having table name result in the appropriate columns.

I can write the storing code myself.
I need a code to retrieve the consecutive td data inside a row without a loop.Since the code to store td data varies.

Posts I referred - [scraping webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862581/need-help-scraping-webpage-getting-specific-content).

Comment: Are you using the SimpleHTMLDom Parser?

Comment: @AmalMurali - S. I used Simple HTML DOM parser from sourceforge..

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.org/");

// Find the tr array
$tr_array = $html->find("table#table2 tr");

$td_array = [];
// Find the td array
foreach($tr_array as $tr) {
    array_push($td_array,$tr->find("td"));
}

echo "<table id=\"table1\">";
foreach($tr_array as $tr) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($td_array as $td) {
        echo $td;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

For advanced topics, read [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

---

In the above code, I've stored array objects inside arrays:

```
<?php

$a = [];
$a1 = [1,2,3];
$a2 = [4,5,6];
array_push($a,$a1,$a2);
foreach($a as $a_e) {
  foreach($a_e as $e) {
    echo $e;
  }
  echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Outputs:

> 123
> 456

Comment: Getting error in the line - `$td_array = [];`
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @SriRam Bhai edit kar diya answer. If it's correct, upvote it or mark it as the answer. Try something from your side - we can show you the way, chalna tujhe padega! :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting all td's in specific table

```
//get into specific table. table number is from 0,1,2,3.. in your whole html returned
$table = $html->find('table', tableNumber);
$td = $html->find('td');
foreach($td as $tds)
{
  echo $tds;
}
```